# Run program in folders

Tags: c#, windows, shell, shell-extensions

I saw that when you assign a GUID to a folder's name for example:

```
GodMode.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}
```

now i want to use that system to open a C# program when you access a folder with a specified guid. I looked up the godmode key and i found a reference in the registry at

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{key}
```

I have found the following data at the registery reference:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLID\{key} : (Standard) REG_SZ = "AllTasks"
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLID\{key} : InfoTip REG_EXPAND_SZ = "@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-32538"
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLID\{key} : LocalizedString REG_EXPAND_SZ = "@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell.dll,-32537"
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLID\{key} : System.AppUserModel.ID REG_SZ = "Microsoft.Windows.ControlPanel"
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLID\{key}\DefaultIcon : (Standard) REG_EXPAND_SZ = "%SystemRoot%\System32\imageres.dll,-27"
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLID\{key}\InProcServer32 : (Standard) REG_EXPAND_SZ = "%SystemRoot%\System32\shell32.dll"
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLID\{key}\InProcServer32 : ThreadingModel REG_SZ = "Apartment"
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLID\{key}\ShellFolder : (Standard) REG_SZ = (no value)
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLID\{key}\ShellFolder : Attributes REG_DWORD = 0x20100004
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLID\{key}\ShellFolder : WanrsFORDISPLAY REG_SZ = ""
```

The important part is that i want that the program or shell extension is run inside the folderbrowser, just like control panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done by creating a [Shell Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff521728%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), specifically by creating a [Folder View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144092%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The topic is too broad to go in depth here on how to create one from start to finish but perhaps knowing the correct term and having those links will at least help get you started.

Note that if you want to use .NET to write your shell extension [Microsoft only officially supports using .NET 4.0 or newer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819091.aspx) for writing shell extensions. This is because 4.0 is the version that supported In-process Side by Side.

Comment: Thanks, thats what i needed, i know a topic like this is a bit heavy to discuss here but i really just needed a point to start working from